# how to access to $_GET in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a little project on Laravel 5.1

And I updated it to 5.2

And now I get this error from my model:

`Class 'Input' not found`

And this is the code :

`if ( \Input::get('angular') ) { ... }`

And where do I find it in the documentation ?

I'm new with Laravel

And I didn't find it

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use:

```
\Request::input('angular')
```

instead of

```
\Input::get('angular')
```

Reference: [Laravel 5.2 Request documention](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests)

Comment: Input::get('angular') can also be used, if you add:  'Input' =>Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class, to "aliases" in config\app.php